# not able to set z-index for Full Screen Slider using css3

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to make a full screen slider using `css` and `jquery`.
So the basic idea is to add and remove classes with `css3` animations.
The slider works fine at first look and when i click a thumb (bottom of screen) the slider changes image beautifully but then again when i click another thumb everything fades out.
What i need is the image according to thumb fades in..
I have created a fiddle with complete comments so that you guys can understand.
i am working hard on this but cannot figure out the problem where i am doing wrong.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#thumbsList>li').click(function () {

        //Getting Id from thumbnail or Full Image Refeence.

    var clickedFullImageId = $(this).data("fullimageid");

    //Save an BG image element which as actually clicked.
    var selectedBigImage = $('.backgroundImages[data-fullImageId="' + clickedFullImageId + '"]');



    //Z index should be placed here somewhere.


    //Removing Animation class of the Images which were not clicked.
    $('.backgroundImages').not(selectedBigImage).addClass('fadeOut', function () {
      $('.backgroundImages').removeClass('animationStuff');

        selectedBigImage.addClass('fadeIn');


    });


    // Displaying the Bg Img which was clicked by Thumb
    selectedBigImage.show();


    selectedBigImage.addClass('animationStuff');

});});
```

The Complete code is found here.
**http://jsfiddle.net/thL7X/**

Please tell me how to handle this. thanks.

Comment: In your fiddle, all the images are broken. It's difficult to see what works and what doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several issues here:

- You are listening for transitionEnd but you aren't differentiating between what is transitioning in and what is transitioning out
- addClass doesn't take a callback function that will tell you when something is complete - the code in those functions is never called
- You will get multiple animationEnd events if multiple properties are being animated
- Your two actions and different classes are clobbering each other.  Between fadeIn/Out and animationStuff things will get a little janky.

I've made several changes to your original code, including some of the styles and managed to get it working. You may need to adjust this a bit more to get the final effect you want.

[Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/thL7X/4/)

Code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //Settings//
    var autoPlay = "True";
    //End Setting//

    //Display Logo //
    $('#logo').delay(1000).fadeIn(3000);

    var currentImage = 0;
    var $backgroundImages = $('.backgroundImages');

    //Setting first image to Display
    var firstBgImage = $backgroundImages.eq(currentImage);
    firstBgImage.show(); //Displays the First Image//
    firstBgImage.addClass('animationStuff coming'); //Starts the Animation of First Image//

    $('.backgroundImages').on("transitionend webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd MSTransitionEnd", function (evt) {
        // If Autplay is True //
        if (autoPlay == "True") {
            /*Fades out First Image and then Removes the Animation Class so that
            be set to 1.33 Zoom level and when clicked again be animated.  */
            var $this = $(this);

            if($this.hasClass('coming')) {
                $this.addClass('going').removeClass('coming').addClass('fadeOut');

                currentImage = (currentImage + 1) % $backgroundImages.length;            

                $backgroundImages.eq(currentImage).hide(function() {
                    $backgroundImages.eq(currentImage).removeClass('fadeOut animationStuff going');
                    $backgroundImages.eq(currentImage).show(function() {
                        $backgroundImages.eq(currentImage).addClass('animationStuff coming'); 
                    });
                });
            }
        }
    });

    $('#thumbsList>li').click(function () {
        autoPlay = false;

        //Getting Id from thumbnail or Full Image Refeence.
        var clickedFullImageId = $(this).data("fullimageid");

        //Save an BG image element which as actually clicked.
        var selectedBigImage = $('.backgroundImages[data-fullImageId="' + clickedFullImageId + '"]');

        //Removing Animation class of the Images which were not clicked.
        $('.backgroundImages.coming').addClass('fadeOut going').removeClass('coming fadeIn');

        selectedBigImage.show(function() {
            selectedBigImage.addClass('fadeIn animationStuff coming').removeClass('fadeOut going');
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks it worked, but there is one question, why is the first image on load animating slower than rest of images which clicked?thanks

Comment: on click the code is using the fadeIn transition which has a shorter interval than the animationStuff transition.